# Regex for removing all attributes from a paragraph

Tags: javascript, regex

I know that regex usually should not be used for parsing html content. In my special case i need them
*(reason is, am using a rte editor and when pasting into the editor some replacement for attributes of paragraphs needs to be done).*

I have something like

```
<p attribute1="val1" attribute2="val2" attribut="val3" ...>text blah blah</p>
```

and i need all attributes stripped out so that i get

```
<p>text blah blah</p>
```

**How can this be done using a regex?**

A solution to strip out attributes from all possible html tags is appreciated too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work on all tags:

```
replace(/<\s*(\w+).*?>/, '<$1>')
```

For paragraphs only, just replace the `\w`:

```
replace(/<\s*p.*?>/, '<p>')
```

The `\s*` in the beginning allows for whitespace before the tag name, so if you for some reason have `< p class="foo">`, it works on that too.

Comment: and what do i use for paragraphs only?

Comment: `< p class="foo">` isn't valid HTML

Comment: Mind, to have this work on *all* matches, you might have to specify the `global` flag either through: `string.replace(/<\s*(\w+).*?>/g, '<$1>')` or `string.replace(new RegExp(/<\s*(\w+).*?>/, 'g'), '<$1>')`

Answer (score 6):

Because an html tag cannot have spaces before the tag name and can continue over multiple lines I would recommend this instead:

```
replace(/<(\w+)(.|[\r\n])*?>/, '<$1>');
```

And for paragraphs only:

```
replace(/<p\s+?(.|[\r\n])*?>/, '<p>');
```

Comment: Worked, but remember to add the g (/<(\w+)(.|[\r\n])*?>/g) if you want to clean up the entire html.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lpe 's/(<\w+)\s+[^>]*/$1/'
```

Comment: sorry, didn't see the javascript tag.  Go with Tatu's sol'n which also allows for the space at the beginning, as noted.